# HTML5 can't create video element on Chromium 38

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-audio, chromium

Until Chromium 37, `var videoElement = document.createElement('video')` would create a video element, but with Chromium 38 it's not the case anymore.

**EDIT**

If you want to check this, open a console and type :

```
var videoElement = document.createElement('video')
videoElement.toString()
```

This should return

```
"[object HTMLVideoElement]"
```

proving `videoElement` is a video element. In Chromium 38 I get :

```
"[object HTMLUnknownElement]"
```

Is there any way to fix this ?

PS: I created an issue on chromium issues : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=427856

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem of having `videoElement.src` as `undefined` on freshly created elements? I suggest you change your JavaScript to cover both cases. This is more specific to some of your own code (which is not in the question), as videos still keep playing fine in the rest of the internet.

Comment: That is just a quick test to show `videoElement` is not a video element. I don't really mind getting `undefined`, but I can't call methods such as `play` or `pause` on `videoElement`.

Comment: You could check for the existence of methods you actually want to use. videoElement.play should be a defined function. On a sidenote, my chrome 38 still does what you expected.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, then how do I create a video element ? I'm using an HTML5 player

Comment: @RenéGeuze I get `undefined` when I try to call `videoElement.play`. I will try with Chrome instead of Chromium.

Comment: What does typing `videoElement` in your console give? That should also give back `<video></video>`. Does video even work at all? Hopefully someone can make some sense of it.

Comment: @RenéGeuze I get `<video></video>` as expected. The problem is it doesn't have the attributes of a video element as it should.

Comment: @René I tried with **Chrome** and everything is OK, only **Chromium** is doing wrong.

Comment: @user284130 I don't see any chromium stable release of version 38? Where have you downloaded it from?

Comment: On your last edit, it should be `videoElement.play` instead of `play()`. the first one gives the function, the second one would give the return value of that function.

Comment: @RahilWazir as you can see here : http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar chromium 38 is the current stable version for Linux. You can get it there : http://chromium.woolyss.com/#ubuntu

Comment: Thank you @René I updated it as I indeed tested `play` and not `play()`. Though, `play()` should return `undefined` and I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: @user284130 Navigating to `chrome://settings/` shows you blank page? It showed to me.

Comment: @RahilWazir yes, moreover when I type something in the search the settings appear, all unchecked.

Comment: @user284130 Thats not good, can you report this bug as well?

Comment: @user284130 Updated chromium has fixed both issues.