# html5 video tag: video.play() "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a page with a video. The video is supposed to automatically pause when the user switches to another tab and restart as soon as the user comes back. We do this by using an eventListener on the "visibilitychange" event, but thats not my problem.

My problem is in fact, that we get tons of error logging when trying to start or restart the player:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'theVideoTag.play()')

The code:

```
// Some time before get it via jQuery
var videoPlayer = $('video');
// And then later
var theVideoTag = videoPlayer.get(0);
log(theVideoTag.toString()) // <- Interesting thing, read further down
theVideoTag.play(); // <- This is where the error happens
```

I've logged extensively. When I try it in my own browsers, the log always say that "theVideoTag" is an "[object HTMLVideoElement]". Great, that's as it should be, and I never get that annoying failure in any of my testing browsers anyway.

But whenever the problem happens the log says that "theVideoTag" was actually an "[object HTMLUnknownElement]".

I would have guessed that these error messages came from some obscure browsers or bots, but no - according to the user agents they are recent Firefoxes, Chromes, IEs, the whole nine yards.

Does anyone have an idea under which circumstances an HTMLVideoElement is not identified as such and instead seen as an HTMLUnknownElement (which of course does not have a play function)? And how to get the video still to play in those circumstances?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - the code you've provided works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yh5x22dg/

Comment: There was a bug on Chromium 38 mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607111/html5-cant-create-video-element-on-chromium-38) related to your issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah, I have the same problem ... I can not replicate it in any browser. I even tried some really obscure ones like Yandex, but I never ever get this problem and it is driving me insane...

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, I saw that question, but chromium 38 has been a loooong time ago, and according to my logs it happens even in the most recent Chrome, the most recent Firefox ... no matter what. If I could get the error to appear in one of my Browser I'd be okay, because then I could try things out, but it just doesn't happen for me.

Comment: I wonder does it have anything to do with media settings within the browser. BTW, what's the src of that video element?

Comment: We give three sources, one for mp4, one for ogg, one for webm.

Comment: are you injecting the player into the DOM (might it not be instantiated)? does the new background tab optimization for Chrome 58 do anything weird?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Nope, sorry ... the video tag and the src tags are literally in the html right from the start. There is nothing really fancy going on with it. What do you mean by "new background tab optimization"? According to my error logs its been all over the place with browser, it's not chrome specific. Yesterday I had the thought that it might be users who do not have the right codecs (or maybe ANY codecs?) installed on their pcs?! But then why would the browser identify the Tag ans an HTMLUnknownElement !? Makes no sense at all.

Comment: It's late, but lately I had a similar problem. The difference in my case was whether "controls" was enabled or not. I got "index.ts:39 ERROR: undefined: undefined" when "controls" was set on the video element. I do not understand the real cause though.